# Add or Subract two columns in a dataframe on basis of column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with has three columns name,amount and type.
I'm trying to add or subract values to user on basis of type

Here's my sample df

```
    name    amount  type                  
0   John    10      ADD
1   John    20      ADD
2   John    50      ADD
3   John    50      SUBRACT
4   Adam    15      ADD
5   Adam    25      ADD
6   Adam    5       ADD
7   Adam    30      SUBRACT
8   Mary    100     ADD
```

My resultant df

```
    name    amount                    
0   John    30      
1   Adam    15      
2   Mary    100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is multiple by `1` if `ADD` and `-1` if `SUBRACT` column and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df['amount'].mul(df['type'].map({'ADD':1, 'SUBRACT':-1}))
                   .groupby(df['name'], sort=False)
                   .sum()
                   .reset_index(name='amount'))
print (df1)
   name  amount
0  John      30
1  Adam      15
2  Mary     100
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['type'].map({'ADD':1, 'SUBRACT':-1}))
0    1
1    1
2    1
3   -1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7   -1
8    1
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

Also is possible specify only negative values with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for multiple by `-1` and all another by `1`:

```
df1 = (df['amount'].mul(np.where(df['type'].eq('SUBRACT'), -1, 1))
                   .groupby(df['name'], sort=False)
                   .sum()
                   .reset_index(name='amount'))
print (df1)

   name  amount
0  John      30
1  Adam      15
2  Mary     100
```

Answer (score 2):

One idea could be to use `Series.where` to change the sign of `amount` accordingly and then  `groupby.sum`:

```
df.amount.where(df.type.eq('ADD'), -df.amount).groupby(df.name).sum().reset_index()

   name  amount
0  Adam      15
1  John      30
2  Mary     100
```